# How can I filter my Azure WebJob function call history by failure?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have an Azure WebJob built using the Azure Web Jobs SDK.  It consumes messages off of a queue and produces messages on another queue.  It has thousands of successes and a handful of failures.  Unfortunately, the only way I can find too look back over the function calls is by paging through all of them.

[image]

Is there some way I can get a list of the failures and get additional details about them such as what was logged or what exception was thrown?

Comment: Have you tried the poison queue and storing the failed message to Azure Table Storage maybe?

Comment: That will show me which messages failed, but it won't give me the logging/exception that lead to the failure.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to log/save the message that failed and then retry it with your debugger attached to the webjob.

Also, **Whatever is written to console output and console error will go to a log file for the specific triggered webjob run.** So before throwing an exception in your try/catch block make sure you log the exception with the details so that you can acceess it later via FTP or the UI.

[Here](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/06/azure-website-logging/#.VE6BrPnF98F) are the details on how/where is everything logged in azure websites. You can access the logs via FTP.

You can also access the information via the REST API. [Details here.](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API)

Hope this helps,

Comment: The REST API looks like what I want.  I'll play with it this evening and see if it helps me find my errors.  The problem with replaying the failure is that it won't fail again if the error was transient (e.g., remote service is down, received unexpected response from remote service, out of memory exception, etc.).

Comment: If it helps, in my application, some messages fail too but then they are reprocessed with no errors. I store the message as an error if and only if it fails more than 5 times via poision queue. In that way I know there's really something wrong with the message.

Comment: I believe Service Bus will move messages that fail to process 10 (by default) times into the dead letter queue.  However, I believe that they are retried back-to-back (after peek timeout) or after `Abandon()` which means if the error is transient due to a dependent service being down they are likely to blow through all 10 failures pretty quick.